# Same "Android resource linking" error for two differnet .xml files in Android Studio

Tags: android, xml

Every time I run my application I get the error "Android resource linking failed".

I have different objects and for all of them I get the error:

> C:\Users\Samuel\AndroidStudioProjects\Carlschwein\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_main.xml:38:
>   error: attribute met_singleLineEllipse (aka
>   com.example.carlschwein:met_singleLineEllipse) not found.

The problem seems to be the app:met_singleLineEllipse="true" but I have to keep it and I can't find any related documentation that might help me.

XML FILE ONE:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"

    app:cardElevation="4dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <com.rengwuxian.materialedittext.MaterialEditText
            android:id="@+id/edtNewUser"
            android:hint="User name"
            android:textColorHint="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:met_baseColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:met_floatingLabel="highlight"
            app:met_primaryColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:met_singleLineEllipse="true"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

XML FILE TWO:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    tools:context="com.example.carlschwein.MainActivity">


        <RelativeLayout

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" >

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/info_login"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"

            app:cardElevation="4dp"
            >

            <LinearLayout
                android:padding="16dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <com.rengwuxian.materialedittext.MaterialEditText
                    android:id="@+id/edtPassword"
                    android:hint="Password"
                    android:textColorHint="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:textSize="24sp"
                    android:inputType="textPassword"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:met_baseColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                    app:met_floatingLabel="highlight"
                    app:met_primaryColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                    app:met_singleLineEllipse="true"
                    />

        </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Anyone has any idea why this might happen/were my mistake is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried this (maybe just a typo):

```
app:met_singleLineEllipsis="true"
```

Method from library [Wiki](https://github.com/rengwuxian/MaterialEditText/wiki)